# .editorconfig Errors/Warnings only showing for files that are open

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, editorconfig

I set up .editorconfig preferences for naming, and I want to see them for all files in our solution, but Visual Studio (2019 16.4.5) only shows the warnings / errors (as defined) If I have the file open in the editor, not for all occurrences in all files, like I want.

How can I see all occurrences of naming rule violations across all files in the solution?

Comment: Could you find a solution to this? I still have this problem with multiple solutions on multiple dev machines... But according to the internet it is only not working on my machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to

> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced

and check

- Enable full solution analysis
- Use .editorconfig compatibility mode

Then restart VS and rebuild solution

Comment: I did this, and I'm still seeing errors / warning pop up after I fix all the occurrences shown in the Error List. It's like it just randomly finds and shows them. So weird. But I assume this should be the accepted answer. I'll investigate some more. This is definitely related to me opening files in the editor, then some new errors pop up. But ironically I'm opening the file because another warning / suggestion is shown for it!

Comment: For anyone else finding this, these setting have been removed in Visual Studio version 16.8 and are no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

In Solution Explorer, right click on your Solution or Project and choose "Analyze and Code Cleanup", then "Run Code Analysis on Solution/Project". This will run the analyzer and show you all the errors/warnings in the whole solution or project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the errors list tool window the top right drop down allows you to select "Current Document" which will filter the list to just the file with focus:

[image]

verses:

[image]

(Note the errors, warnings, and messages counts still show there are other places with issues.)

Also the extension [Solution Error Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.SolutionErrorVisualizer) may be helpful.